# Report SharePoint Group Membership Changes: Users added to Groups and removed from Groups

Tags: 2013, 2010, groups, reporting

How to track users created and users deleted from a SharePoint group? I want to generate a report on daily basis of how many users were created and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site collection audit level event that can be enabled. Go to Site Settings and click on Site collection audit settings in the Site administration section. Tick the box for Editing users and permissions. This will start to aggregate statistics on permission changes.

You can then run audit log reports against this data.